# Avoid requests that take much time Apache

Tags: php, apache, ddos

I was about to programm a class that validates data from browsers and one of those methods validates length of strings, then something came to my mind: What if somebody sends a very big string with 2 millions of characters or more (or whatever) ?

If I use strlen() to count bytes, it will count to the last bytes.
It would be a waste to count all those bytes.

After thinking for a while, I made something like this:

```
   Class Validator
    {
     static public function verify_str_length($str, $min, $max)
     {   
       $i;
       $counter = $min;
       $msg = "";
      // looling until null char is found
      //
       for($i=$min-1;$i<$max;$i++) {
          if(!isset($str[$i])) {
            if($i == ($min -1)) {
                // if first iteration
                // we find the null char so early.
                // $i starts with the minimum length allowed, the string
                // length is lower than that so it is too short
                $msg = 'Too short string';
                return -1;
            }
             return 0;
         }

      }
       if(isset($str[$i])) {
         // if we reach the max and keep without finding the null char so
         // the string length is higher than $max
          $msg = 'Too long string';
           return 1;
      }
       return 0;
       }
      //
    /*  Others Methods 
         ..... */
   }
```

Note that I do not need the number of characters in the string, only if it higher than $min and lower than $max. I will discard all others chars.

My question is: would it be a good idea to do so instead of using strlen() ?

Is there another way to do this like configurate APACHE to stop execution if the server takes more than X seconds in processing the request ?

Or can I use both options?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No.  Use strlen.

Comment: Thanks for responding. How can I avoid from counting unnecessary bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's **post_max_size** directive to limit the amount of content submitted.  Be careful with this setting because if you have file uploads, they will have to fit within this size as well.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

To limit the amount of time spent parsing input data, you may use **max_input_time**.

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time

To limit the execution time,  use **max_execution_time**.

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

You may set these in .htaccess, like so:

```
php_value post_max_size 1M
php_value max_execution_time 30
php_value max_input_time 5
```

For validation, you should use PHP's **filter** functions, for example:

```
$content = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'content', FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, [ 'options' => ['regexp' => '/^[\w-]{1,64}$/']] );
```

This will ensure that if $_POST['content'] is not composed of letters, digits, underscores or hyphens, and is not between 1 and 64 characters long, it will not be accepted.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php